# Migrating from http to https in android with Volley

Tags: android, networking, ssl, heroku, android-volley

I have a service running without SSL right now and I'm using Volley to consume the APIs. If at some point I do enable SSL, how do I ensure that people can continue using older versions of the app which have a SSL disabled url.

Answer (score 1):

On the server side, add the SSL enabled endpoints you need, but keep the old ones for the transition period until it's "safe" to phase them out.

There's nothing special to be done on the client side.